# Mixare iOS call from ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, augmented-reality

I have iOS 6 app and I'd like to add one more ViewController (storyboard) in which it would be augmented reality. Now, I'm using Mixare, and I could start AR, but cannot exit the view.

I used this [tutorial](https://github.com/eXaLy/mixare-iphone/wiki/How-to-use-Mixare-as-library) for implementation Mixare as library into my project.

I think that problem is that I'm calling MixareAppDelegate

```
MixareAppDelegate *delegate = [[MixareAppDelegate alloc] init];
[delegate runApplication];
```

that uses self.window.rootViewController

```
self.window.rootViewController = augViewController;
```

After that, I can close view, but app freezes. Is there anywhere tutorial how to call Mixare as one view in storyboard with navigation?

Is there easy way to call MixareAppDelegate which is a ViewController as viewController not as element in window.rootViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only interact with one window at a time.
When you have added the MixareAppDelegate's window then previous window get invisible for further interaction. You have to visible previous window again.
try: 
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
it will solve all of your issues.